# Synchronised Keyword

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing an app which downloads images and saves them to the sdcard. The class which interacts with the sdcard looks like this...

```
public class SDCardImageManagerImp implements SDCardImageManager {

    private Context context;

    @Inject
    public SDCardImageManagerImp(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void saveToSDCard(String id, Bitmap bitmap) throws FileNotFoundException {
        FileOutputStream outputStream = context.openFileOutput(id, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getImage(String id) throws FileNotFoundException {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.openFileInput(id));
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteImage(String id) {
        context.deleteFile(id);
    }

}
```

This class is a singleton as I read writing to a disk with multiple threads can hinder performance. However I do have multiple threads downloading the data and sending it to this class. So my questions is should all of the methods in this class have the syncronized key work on them?

Comment: That seems a bit heavy-handed to me.  What you really should be aiming for is to block only if it's the same `id`.  Otherwise you're going to serialize everything, and it won't run as fast as it could.

Comment: @ToddSjolander: I don't know if the assumption is valid (that you should serialize I/O to the SD card), but if it is, it does make sense to do this per device (or globally, which amounts to the same thing), not per file.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. How would it serialize everything if I syncronized all the methods?

Comment: @Thilo: That's true, it might require serialized access.  I'm not sure about how SD cards handle that.  So the safe (possibly slower) way is to just synchronize everything.

Comment: @jiduvah: Every method in an object with the `synchronized` keyword is forced to execute one at a time.  So any methods you call will not execute until every earlier call is completely finished.

Comment: yeah I got it in the end. I guess you ment to write "syncronized" rather than "serialized" on your first comment

Comment: "Serialized" is good, too. It means that things happen in a series (as opposed to concurrently). A term from the database transaction world. (A bit confusing because it has nothing to do with Java object serialization).

Comment: Ah ok, yes that was confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not create a Thread Pool of Image Writers using the `writerThreadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads)`.  This way, you call `writerThreadPool.submit()` allowing the image to be queued up for writing as a thread becomes available.  The Thread Pool will handle the io throttling for you, since it will only ever allow the given number of threads that you create.  And by using the `Executors.newFixedThreadPool`, you can easily play with the number of threads by changing `numThreads` to allow more or less threads to get the desired performance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the assumption is valid (that you should throttle I/O to the SD card), but even if it is, you probably want to make this configurable, which the synchronized keyword will not let you.

How about something like a counting [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) (and a configuration file to set the number of permits)?

Comment: Strange you should mention Semaphore, I never used them before but read about them earlier today. I will see how it works out

Comment: But first check if this throttling is really necessary. One would hope that the disk driver and Android I/O sub-system can manage this on its own.

Comment: Its a little difficult to do actually. I am using robolectric so I can't write to sdcard using that framework. I guess I should setup some standard android tests and run them on the emulator

Comment: Also, it's probably easier to just throttle the process from the other end (number of concurrent picture download threads and intervals in between).